# Is there a list of HTML5 elements that can be nested inside other elements?

Tags: html, w3c

I'm trying to figure out **which HTML tags** can be **nested** in **other HTML tags** so I can write a *valid HTML 5* document for W3C and respect the *flow*.

Is there a list that contains for each HTML tag all the elements it can contain?

For example for the **`<a>`** tag it can contain:

```
TT | I | B | BIG | SMALL | EM | STRONG | DFN | CODE | SAMP | 
KBD | VAR | CITE | ABBR | ACRONYM | A | IMG | OBJECT | BR | 
SCRIPT | MAP | Q | SUB | SUP | SPAN | BDO | INPUT | SELECT | TEXTAREA | LABEL | BUTTON
```

I have already searched on W3C or Google but it's needed to search for each tag.

Comment: You could look at the source code of an open source editor that checks for valid syntax. Presumably, they've done all of the work for you, and you can just copy them.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I generally write my pages as ".xhtml" rather than ".html".  Browsers can then be very picky and will immediately point out anything that doesn't strictly conform to the standard.  You'll get instant feedback every time you refresh the page you're working on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#elements-3
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#element-content-categories

Since these helpful sections are marked as '*non-normative*', technically you'd have to go to each element listing (a's, for example: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) and check the Content model definition, which isn't always 100% straightforward, but could still probably be consumed fairly usefully programmatically.

There are pages here and there on the internet with such lists if you can't be bothered; you would just have to trust that they compiled their lists properly against the spec.

The W3C has given control of HTML5 over to the WHATWG.
https://www.w3.org/html/
http://w3.org/tr/html5

Historically (HTML5 has changed the rules on this some), inline elements can be children of most things and block elements cannot be children of inline elements, so just having an idea what is inline and what is block (block elements take up available width by default, typically forcing preceding & following elements linearly above & below), will go a long way.

Comment: Those documents are very useful, they also contain the *attributes* that each element can accept. Many thanks, even if we would prefer a list containing all the tags and their nestable elements.

Comment: A _script_ to consume the spec to generate this list would be useful indeed. A mere list compiled by someone I would personally always suspect as potentially inaccurate. I'm sure someone will get around to it, if indeed no one has already.

Comment: "The W3C uses a validator that validates against the WHATWG's spec": Do you mean https://validator.w3.org/nu/? I think this instance of the tool validates against W3C’s most recent spec.

Comment: @unor Nope, that one validates against WHATWG's. I find it odd myself, but that is what it does.

Comment: @JanKyuPeblik: What makes you think that? You can easily test it yourself: try to validate a document with two `main` elements (WHATWG: valid; W3C: invalid).

Comment: @unor Nope, both W3C and WHATWG specs presently disallow two 'main' elements. Not for nothing, but I think your time would be better spent if you look things up before asserting them as fact. As you can see, I'm happy to have a casual conversation where uncertain assertions are tested and either rebutted or not, as happens frequently in ordinary in-person, real-time conversation; but it does become tedious at a certain point, particularly in a medium such as this.

Comment: @JanKyuPeblik: Sorry, I didn’t notice that the WHATWG spec got changed ([in 2018-01](https://web.archive.org/web/20180122173336/https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-main-element), multiple `main` elements were still allowed; and https://validator.nu/ still checks against the old version). -- I searched the w3.org checker’s issue tracker and found out that it, indeed, uses WHATWG’s spec ([since 2018-11](https://github.com/validator/validator/issues/725#issuecomment-436222906)). The reason seems to be that the W3C wants to converge the HTML spec with the WHATWG.

Comment: @unor Yea. I'm sure they have some kind of reason. The W3C is still a name more people know, but if the WHATWG is the force of progress (good or bad), eventually people will realize that. Competition is an interesting thing.

Answer (score 0):

you can also hav `<div>` inside the `<a>` tag and much more.

You could always read the HTML standard documentation (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/),

but as this will take a really long time I would suggest just starting to write your code, and assume that everything is possible ;)

THEN check your finished code with some Validity checker like https://validator.w3.org/